# Type check with enabled StrictFunctionTypes

Tags: typescript

Is impossible to type check this code with enabled strictFunctionTypes?

```
interface CommonBook {
    a: string;
}

interface GoodBook extends CommonBook {
    b: string;
}

interface BadBook extends CommonBook {
    c: string;
}

type ListRenderItem<ItemT> = (item: ItemT) => null;

const renderBook = (renderAnyBook: ListRenderItem<CommonBook>) => renderAnyBook({ a: '' });

const renderGoodBook: ListRenderItem<GoodBook> = () => null;

renderBook(renderGoodBook);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20CommonBook%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20GoodBook%20extends%20CommonBook%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20BadBook%20extends%20CommonBook%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ListRenderItem%3CItemT%3E%20%3D%20(item%3A%20ItemT)%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20renderBook%20%3D%20(renderAnyBook%3A%20ListRenderItem%3CCommonBook%3E)%20%3D%3E%20renderAnyBook(%7B%20a%3A%20''%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20renderGoodBook%3A%20ListRenderItem%3CGoodBook%3E%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0ArenderBook(renderGoodBook)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: What's the desired behavior? It's certainly possible to make renderBook accept a wider range of ListRenderItems, but if you do so `renderAnyBook({ a: '' })` will become an error, since `{ a: '' }` will only fit a `ListRenderItem<CommonBook>`, not something like `ListRenderItem<GoodBook>`

Comment: I want to have renderBook function which will take renderGoodBook or renderBadBook without errors

Comment: Ok. And what do you want to pass into renderGoodBook or renderBadBook? Passing in `{ a: '' }` will be an error, because that is not a goodBook/badBook.

Answer (score 0):

To make renderBook work with a variety of render functions, while still enforcing type safety, you can turn it into a generic:

```
const renderBook = <T extends CommonBook>(renderAnyBook: ListRenderItem<T>) => 
  renderAnyBook({ a: '' });
```

However, if you do this, you'll find an error: You're calling `renderAnyBook({ a: '' })`, but that would only work if the function was called with a `ListRenderItem<CommonBook>`. If called with a `ListRenderItem<GoodBook>`, for example, then you need to pass a GoodBook into renderAnyBook, and `{ a: '' }` is not a GoodBook.

As best i can tell from the information provided, this is typescript doing its job to point out that your code has a bug. The function as written isn't calling renderAnyBook correctly and will need to be modified. The exact modifications i can't tell without more info. Perhaps you need to loosen the types on GoodBook/BadBook so that the extra properties are optional.